# How do I deploy and run an applications on K8s?

Tags: reactjs, docker, kubernetes, flask

I've built a React & Flask app that is working perfectly fine on my local computer.

Now I try to run my app on Kubernetes. I wrote the deployment and service files, I applied them and execute the minikube sever my-app command.

After that the webpage of my app is opened but none of the functionality works. When I inspect at the network calls I get an (failed)net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error when trying reaching some endpoint on my backend (the HTTP calls are to localhost:5000).

My front-end files are static (ran React build) and again the HTTP calls from the front end are to localhost:5000/endpoint (maybe I should change it since I've built the frontend files).

I think that my deployment and service files are because they are pretty basic. So I really think that the whole problem is in the URL/ports area.

Example of HTTP request call from the frontend:

```js
  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    const url = apiUrl + '/deleteToDo';
    axios.delete(url, { data: { ToDoid: id } }).then((res) => {
      console.log("Task deleted successfully.");
      updateTodos(res.data); 
    });
  }
```

Partial code from my backend:

```py
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder=r'/app/my-app/build', static_url_path='/')

#CORS(app, supports_credentials=True, origins=["http://localhost:3000"])
CORS(app)

@app.route("/todo")
@app.route("/")

def catch_all():
    return app.send_static_file("index.html")

## some functions

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

`deployment.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-deployment
  labels:
    app: todo-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: todo-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: todo-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: todo-app
        image: uchihaligazzz/app
        env:
        - name: FLASK_ENV
          value: development
        - name: FLASK_APP
          value: ./Backend/server.py
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
```

service.yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: todo-app-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: todo-app
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
      protocol: TCP
      nodePort: 31110
```

Comment: Fundamentally, that's not how web applications work. The React client code is running in **your users' browsers**, not on the server. So `localhost` is _their local machine_, not the API service container. You need to correctly configure the app to run in that environment (however you deploy it; this isn't a k8s-specific problem).

Comment: When you deploy, you **must** use the IP/DNS name of the deployed service. On Kubernetes you often map this through an [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) and not through a direct `NodePort` mapping. You should not see `localhost` anywhere but during development.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the URLs and ports being used were causing the issue. The frontend files are static, so the URLs in the http calls from the frontend should be changed to match the Kubernetes service name and port. The backend is running on port 5000, but the http calls from the frontend are to localhost:5000/endpoint, which will not work. You can try to have the http calls to the Kubernetes name and port defined in the service.yaml file. You may want to consider checking CORS for any errors related and try configuring CORS in the Flask backend.